# MYSQL Node.js parse error and throw err error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
> ^
>
> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a', 'b', 'c'' at line 1

(I had entered a as the name,b as the username and c as the password in the form)

I can't figure out where the problem is.

db.js:

```
function createUser(name, username, password){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,password) VALUES ?";
    var values = [name, username, password];
    con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('inserted');
    });
  }

  module.exports = {createUser};
```

relevant part of server.js:

```
app.post('/create', function(req,res) {
  db.createUser(req.body.name,req.body.username,req.body.password);
  res.status(200).send();
});
```

Comment: You nesting your ``values`` array inside another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need additional square brackets around the values:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,password) VALUES ?";
var values = [[name, username, password]];
con.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) { ... });
```

This mechanism is mostly meant to insert multiple rows. You could also separate the parameters:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
var values = [name, username, password];
con.query(sql, values, function (err, result) { ... });
```

Comment: The first one works, the second method gives the same error. Thanks though!

Comment: @jpj: the second code block should work too. Did you notice that I removed the square brackets around `values` in the `query()` call of the second code block?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add for every variable a placeholder

```
function createUser(name, username, password){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?);";
    var values = [name, username, password];
    con.query(sql, values, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('inserted');
    });
  }

  module.exports = {createUser};
```